# Using MassTransit with Azure Service Bus - Setting up Paired Namespaces

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

We've been PoC-ing MassTransit on Azure Service Bus and are looking at ways of ensuring resiliency in the event of an ASB outage.

One option is using Azure's [Paired Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-paired-namespaces) functionality, which puts messages on backlog queues in a secondary namespace if the primary one is unavailable. ASB, then takes care of siphoning messages back to the primary namespace once it is available.

I've not been able to find a way to set this up through MassTransit.
Is this possible at all?

Comment: Paired Namespace feature is deprecated, along with the old Azure Service Bus package. Please don't use it.

Comment: @SeanFeldman - Paired namespaces are still clearly supported by Azure, as per their documentation. Are you saying this was once supported by MassTransit and has been deprecated? If so, is there a reason as to why? I can't find any literature in github or the google discussion about this

Comment: Switching to an answer as my comment is too long 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paired namespaces is a feature baked into the old (read *legacy*) Azure Service Bus client [`WindowsAzure.ServiceBus`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/).

Moving forward, the client to use is (and recommended by Microsoft)

> This is the next generation Azure Service Bus .NET Standard client library that focuses on queues & topics.

is [`Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/). Which is .NET Sdandard / .NET Core compliant implementation.
If you're willing to use the feature that is A) not recommended (read [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/service-bus-ha-with-paired-namespaces) why) B) is deprecated from the new client and won't be implemented, by all means.

MassTransit neither relies on this feature nor do I see a good reason to bother to support it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Are you aware of any similar functionality that Microsoft intends to or has already introduced which would offer HA without the client having to do very much? Alternatively, would you see good reason for MassTransit to support a failover namespace?

Comment: That feature is combination of Premium tier with Availability Zones. Provides HA with a single dedicated namespace.